# Why can't I append with R's write function

Tags: r

Pardons if this has already been answered, I didn't see anything quite like this.  I want to create a running log but I can't get the write function to append.  Here is a sample:

```
fName <- "D:/Temp/foo.txt"
fCn <- file(fName)
write('test1', fCn, append = TRUE)
write('test2', fCn, append = TRUE)
close(fCn)
```

When I open the resulting file I only see the last line.  I have also tried opening and closing the file like so:

```
fCn <- file(fName)
write('test1', fCn, append = TRUE)
close(fCn)

fCn <- file(fName)
write('test2', fCn, append = TRUE)
close(fCn)
```

Seems like it should be easy.  Where am I going wrong?  TIA

Comment: Probably because you haven't specified a mode for the file connection (e.g. `file(...,open = "w")`. Without a default, each call to `write` probably resets the connection somehow in trying to determine what you intended.

Comment: ...indeed, since `write` calls `cat` and in `?cat` we see: "If file is a connection and open for writing it is written from its current position. If it is not open, it is opened for the duration of the call in "wt" mode and then closed again."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the connection in *append* mode:

```
> fCn <- file(fName,open="a")
```

Full example:

```
> fName="out1.txt"
> fCn <- file(fName,open="a")
> write('test1', fCn, append = TRUE)
> write('test2', fCn, append = TRUE)
> close(fCn)
```

Results in both strings written to the file.

Alternatively you can just write to the file *name* (not a connection object) with `append=TRUE`:

```
> write('test1', "out2.txt", append = TRUE)
> write('test2', "out2.txt", append = TRUE)
```

also results in a two-line output file, created from scratch.

Comment: The only problem is that it appends to the last line and not starting a new line for the first `write`. Can that be resolved or you have to write a blank line each time?

Comment: I suspect you are running on windows and may need to use a mode of `"at"` to open in text mode. I see perfect line breaks with the code above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sink` for this purpose. It is always easier to write what you can actually see in R console to a text file so you are sure about the output.

```
sink("C:/Users/mahdisoltanim/Desktop/a.txt", append= TRUE)
cat("\n")
cat("test1")
cat("\n")
cat("test2")
sink()
```